# Loading JS ES6 module in the browser

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, systemjs

I am trying to learn how to load a simple ES6 moduel in the browser. Since i read that ES6 modules are not supported yet by the browsers I desided to do that with SystemJS. Example the following file:

```
export class AbstractLogger {
    constructor(name) {

       console.log("Hello from constructor");
    }
    setNextLogger() {
        console.log("Hello from method");
    }

}
AbstractLogger.INFO = 1;
AbstractLogger.DEBUG = 2;
AbstractLogger.ERROR = 3;
```

When i use SystemJS to to that i get the following error.

SystemJS.import('AbstractLogger.js');

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: XHR error:  loading file:///home/tito/Projects/test/AbstractLogger.js
  Instantiating file:///home/tito/Projects/test/AbstractLogger.js
  Loading AbstractLogger.js
    at XMLHttpRequest.error (system.src.js:1491)
    at system.src.js:1528
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at xhrFetch (system.src.js:1480)
    at fetchFetch (system.src.js:1448)
    at system.src.js:3394
    at <anonymous>
```

If i understand that correctly i can not load ES6 modules directlly in the browser yet since this is not supported. Even if i provide the type='module' in the script tag this is not working. Then how are we suppose to load them at all? I

Comment: Is the path to `AbstractLogger.js` correct?

Comment: yes the path is correct , if i click of the path i get the js file displayed as text in Chrome so i know that the path is correct. If it was not correct i guess i would be getting 404 or something similar

Comment: I think you'd get a `Error: XHR error:  loading file` error

Comment: maybe but this is not the error in this case

Comment: That's the error you've posted in your question.

Comment: yes but like i said if i click on the link "file:///home/tito/Projects/test/AbstractLogger.js" i get the file displayed so the path is right

Comment: That's a local file path. Are you not running a server?

Comment: No i am not running a server I want to use SystemJS since i would be using this javascript later on without a server on a client side

Comment: Does it mean that it  can not use it without a  server?

Comment: You can't. As the files are loaded using a XHR request, which can't be done over the `file` protocol. Check the error `Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.` (chrome) --- If you want a simple local server, use https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Comment: I jst tried it with a server i.e. "emrun"  and loaded it in a page using the  now i ma getting the error "Unexpected token export " in FF 56

Comment: system.src.js:80 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unable to dynamically transpile ES module
   A loader plugin needs to be configured via `SystemJS.config({ transpiler: 'transpiler-module' })`.
  Instantiating http://localhost:8080/AbstractLogger.js
  Loading AbstractLogger.js
    at transpile (system.src.js:3690)
    at system.src.js:3472
    at <anonymous>
LoaderError__Check_error_message_for_loader_stack @ system.src.js:80
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:282
Promise rejected (async)
SystemJSLoader$1.import @ system.src.js:3918
(anonymous) @ MinimalTLV.html:26

Comment: If i do the same trick with SystemJS i get the error message above

Comment: @ evolutionxbox many thanks i thing you got me further i will dig in on the next error i'v got,and  thanks for your help again

Comment: Check systemjs's README. You need to install a transpiler for in browser transpilation.